# IE9 HTML5 video visible only after cache clearing

Tags: html, video, internet-explorer-9

The html5 video is working in all browsers. Except that in IE9 it shows only after the cache is cleared;

The second page refresh after clearing the cache no longer displays the popup;

The video is inside a foundation 3 reveal. IE9 Developer Tools shows the computed css:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
float: none;
height: 416px;
width: 640px;
visibility: visible;
```

But if this would have been a css problem the video would have never been shown.
Also, the video plays fine, there are no encoding issues.

Possible duplicate of
[IE9+8 HTML5 Video - video loads but "invisible"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685722/ie98-html5-video-video-loads-but-invisible)

**EDIT** Added a showcase of the bug [click here](http://321zeno.com/staging/videotest/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick fix, I removed the video's height attribute from the css and added it using javascript in the callback triggered after the modal is opened.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered but I encountered this issue and this may help someone in the future.

I added `autoplay` as an attribute and the mp4 appeared for me. Here is an example of my working video

```
<video  width="680" height="520" autoplay loop controls src="source-of-vido.mp4">
 </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on your local machine or from a server? In IE browser, you might try...
F12 > Cache > select Always refresh from server

It's hard to know what you've got set up in your IE browser. :) Best k

Comment: I'm testing from a server. As setting the cache refresh may work for me it will not fix the problem for the rest of the visitors.